# ManyToOne dropdown in Django admin inline

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project for keeping track of computers and parts. I have several different models set up for various types of parts, and they have a foreign key pointing to a model for a built computer. As it stands I can only assign a computer to a part, but I would like to do the opposite.

Given something like the following:

**models.py**

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    pass

class PartType1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    installed_in = models.ForeignKey(Computer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class PartType2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    installed_in = models.ForeignKey(Computer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I created some inlines hoping that would work:

**admin.py**

```
class PartType1Inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PartType1

class PartType2Inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PartType2

@admin.register(Computer)
class ComputerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PartType1Inline, PartType2Inline, )
```

But this only allows me to create new parts from the Computer page. Because a computer can have an arbitrary number of a specific type of part (RAM modules as an example) I can't add the foreign keys to the Computer class. I've tried using OneToOne fields on the Computer class, but that requires adding a bunch of fields that usually end up going unused, and is not as flexible. What I would really like is a simple dropdown allowing me choose existing objects from PartType1, PartType2 etc. How can I achieve this?